# Multiple sitemaps within single sitemap file

Tags: seo, sitemap

I have a site with a sitemap, around 150 entries to URLs that are static on the site. `lastmod` element is set to 2012. This sitemap was updated approximately a year ago.

The last couple of lines of this SM file are:

```
  <url><loc>http://example.com/sitemap2.xml</loc><changefreq>daily</changefreq></url>
  <url><loc>http://example.com/siteMap3.xml</loc><changefreq>daily</changefreq></url>
</urlset>
```

**Sitemap 2** contains the same logic but with links targetting specific *products* and **sitemap 3** does the same but aimed towards *categories*. These two are generated daily.

The main `sitemap.xml` is registered. An external SEO advisor ran a test and advised the sitemap is not updated and does not list the links for products and categories.

How could I check if what he has said is correct? If he is correct what could I have done wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having multiple sitemaps is fine, but you should link them from a [sitemap index file](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#index).

For your case, you could use something like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">

   <sitemap>
      <loc>http://example.com/sitemap1.xml</loc>
      <lastmod>2012</lastmod>
   </sitemap>

   <sitemap>
      <loc>http://example.com/sitemap2.xml</loc>
      <lastmod>2016-10-11</lastmod>
   </sitemap>

   <sitemap>
      <loc>http://example.com/sitemap3.xml</loc>
      <lastmod>2016-10-11</lastmod>
   </sitemap>

</sitemapindex>
```

Instead of `changefreq`, you have to use `lastmod`, which takes the date of the last modification of the sitemap (not of the sitemap entries).

This sitemap index file can then be linked in your robots.txt (and/or be submitted to search engines).

Comment: Thanks for your reply (sorry for the delay i just didnt get an alert), if i was to make the above change would it have any detrimental affects on the current SEO procedures? OR would google have to re-index the entire site which means we would be listed at the bottom of a users search. When i check, some products and categories are listed but on page 2/3 of a google search, so i think the SEO guy maybe slightly wrong with his findings

Comment: @Computer: It shouldn’t affect your rankings. Search engines typically don’t need the sitemap to begin with, it’s only a tool that can help them to find (updated) pages more quickly. So if a search engine already indexed your pages, they would have no reason to change something about it if you change (or even delete) your sitemap.